# How to use command line arguments with find in bash script?

Tags: bash, find

I have a hard time writing simple script using find command. I want to delete files with given size in some directory. I want to be able to specify names of files (like Efficiency_*) and size of files to delete. I tried following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
CD=($pwd)
find $CD -name $1 -size $2 -delete
```

I am running it from the correct directory as follows:

```
/path/to/directory/script.sh 'Efficiency_*' '-500c'
```

but it does not work.

What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: I think the problem is your assignment to `CD`. Why are you using an array there?

Comment: Where do you set the variable `$pwd`?

Comment: To debug shell scripts, put `set -x` at the beginning so you see each command as it's being executed.

Comment: Why do you even need that variable? If you want to start in the current directory, use `find .` instead of `find $CD`.

Comment: `find . -name "$1"...` will work just fine :) or if you insist: `CD=$(pwd); find "$CD" -name "$1"...`

Comment: Because my script is in different directory than the one I am running it from. However, it does not change anything, still does not work.

Comment: @PesaThe How do I run it? How to write arguments in the command line?

Comment: @Suzie The location of the script does not matter; the script will inherit the working directory of whatever process executes the script, and `pwd` and `.` will both refer to that same directory. (In fact, it's difficult for a script to find out its own location; see [BashFAQ #28](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028).)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need the `CD` variable, just use `.` to refer to the current directory.

And the other variables need to be quoted. Otherwise, the shell will expand the wildcard instead of passing it to `find`.

```
#!/bin/bash
find . -name "$1" -size "$2" -delete
```

In general, you should always quote variables unless you have a specific reason not to.

Comment: How to run this script? How to write arguments in the command line?

Comment: Does it matter if I run it with single quotes or double qoutes? ./script.sh "Efficiency_*" "-500c"   or  ./script.sh 'Efficiency_*' '-500c' ?

Comment: @Suzie, the script itself literally can't tell what quotes were used when starting it. The interpreter that the command is typed into is responsible for breaking the arguments into an array of C strings, so by the time the script is started, it gets an argv that (in C syntax) is something like `string[][]{"./script.sh", "Efficiency_", "-500c", NULL}` -- thing is, it looks exactly like that no matter if it's `Efficiency_` or `'Efficiency_'` or `"Efficiency_"` that was originally entered by the user (or, say, a glob pattern like `Eff*` when a file named `Efficiency_` exists).

Comment: @Suzie It doesn't matter. Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the value you give to the CD-variable. In Bash scripts you have two different ways to assign the output of a program call to a variable ...

```
# method 1
CD=`pwd`

# method 2
CD=$(pwd)
```

Comment: ...though none of these is particularly good practice in the context at hand. `cd=$PWD` is much more efficient than running a subshell (thus, `fork()`ing off a whole separate copy of the shell) just to find the current directory.

Comment: And `find .` is usually better than `find "$PWD"` unless you specifically need `find` to output the full path.

Comment: @tripleee in this case me too, but it's in general good to know - for more complicated scripts